# Error in TFS build

Tags: tfsbuild

I am getting the following error in my build process:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "xyz" because it was not found

I know that this file doesn't exist,  but I can't find where that copy has been set. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Really hard to diagnose with so little info. First thing to do is to try and repro the issue outside of TFS build on your workstation. Is your TFS build setup to build the release configuration for example? Can you build like that locally?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed on the Build Server?

Answer (score 0):

That targets file is usually called when publishing a web application.  If you project references files that aren't checked in, this can cause this to fail.